# Differentiating homographs

Tags: ambiguity, homographs

> A homograph (from the Greek: ὁμός, homós, "same" and γράφω, gráphō, "write") is a word that shares the same written form as another word but has a different meaning. When spoken, the meanings may be distinguished by different pronunciations, in which case the words are also heteronyms.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph

Disambiguation may be difficult at times, especially when a heteronym is used in writing.  This occurred to me the first time I saw an orange juice box of “minute maid” and the small figure of a woman on it.   I wondered then, whether the producers meant  a period of time equal to sixty seconds [mi'nit], or “tiny, exceptionally small” [mai.nyoot'].  Having never seen a commercial before, would a native speaker understand the exact meaning right away ?  Are there other instances when you felt confused by a written heteronym ?

N.B. Someone has already asked what "minute maid" means, but my question goes beyond that.
p.s. Feel free to edit the phonetic symbols, if you know how to do it. I simply couldn't type the correct ones.

Comment: There's more than one ambiguity here: there's both the minute (as in /mai'nju:t/) maid(en) in the picture, but also the fact that the juice is in a minute (/'minət/) made. The paronomasia requires both seeing the writing and the picture, and knowing that it's juice—and of course also knowing what all the different heterhomonymographs mean.

Comment: Are puns in general outside the scope of your question? Because, as an example, there are many titles of books and movies that seem to imply a deeper meaning than what the title suggests. Many times, these titles indicate both a place and an action using the same words. Example: "Blood shed". (roughly. Please don't quibble about the space or not.)

Answer (score 0):

“Minute” (=a sixtieth part of an hour) and “minute” (=very small) are etymologically the same word (Latin minutus), but they have been secondarily distinguished in their pronunciation. If you define “homograph” as “a word of the same spelling as another, but of different origin and meaning” (thus the OED), then they are not homographs, as they are not of “different origin”. I would call them etymological doublets.

Comment: AHDEL, Collins, RHK Webster's, the Google Dictionary, I think Macmillan, and Wiktionary consider the noun and the adjective usages to have diverged so far that they must now be classed as separate words rather than polysemes. And Collins, RHK Webster's, M-W and Wikipedia would label them homographs.

Answer (score -1):

A Boston marketing firm came up with the name Minute Maid, implying the juice was quick and easy to prepare.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_Maid#History

In this specific case (Minute Maid), the title is a play on words and is specifically intended to be ambiguous. Thus the exact meaning is more than one meaning simultaneously.

Comment: That's not the question that was asked.

Comment: it's a play on words, the exact meaning is intentionally ambiguous. How, in this case, is anyone to know the exact meaning right away? And how would they know they are correct if they did?

Comment: you are supposed to know that the first word is "60 seconds" not "extremely tiny". The pun/play may be on maid/made but the question is about "minute"

Comment: why can't the pun be on both words? The drawing of a small maid could imply they may have meant to. My point is that a play on words is intended to be ambiguous in (perhaps) every instance.